# Showing that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is an abelian group

Tags: abelian-groups

**QUESTION**

Multiplication of complex numbers defines a binary operation on $\mathbb{C}^\times := \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ together with this operation is an abelian group.

**ATTEMPT**

I know that for an abelian it has to show commutativity and for it to be a group there must be associativity of multiplication, but not sure where to go with it.

Comment: Do you have to show that it is a group, or do you know that it is a group and have to show that it is abelian?

Comment: I have to try to show that it is abelian, and yeah we know that it is a group

Answer (score 4):

**Big Hint**

using the fact that $\mathbb R$ is abelian, we can very easily prove that

$$(a+ib)(c+id)=...=(c+id)(a+ib)$$
for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$.